# In MVC 6, URL rewriting

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have one authentication site, and it receives requests from multiple sites(site 1,2,3) for authenticate the user.

exp:

1. site/site 1/controller/action

2. site/site 2/controller/action

3. site/site 3/controller/action

I would like to display above URLs as

site/custom text/controller/action

I need to replace the site 1, site 2,site 3 as custom text

and perform the actions ...

Please help on this.....

Regards
P

Answer (score 0):

```
    Yes can can do it by some simple steps 
    1.)Add the custom MapRoute in Startup.cs file in  app.UseMvc section like this :-



     app.UseMvc(routes =>
                {
                    routes.MapRoute(
                       name: "team",
                       template: "Site/{DiffrentSiteName}/{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                       defaults: new { controller = "DefaultcontrollerName ", action = "Index" }
                }); 

    2.)Then in the default control index method get that site name like this 



      public IActionResult Index(string DiffrentSiteName)
                {
                   var siteName = DiffrentSiteName;
                    return view();
                }
    3.)We have to use the same name to get the value of site from the url 
in controller like we have used above (DiffrentSiteName in url and in 
index method)


    4.) So the url will be like :
    1.)http:Site/Site1name/controller/action/parm
    2.)http:Site/Site2name/controller/action/parm
    3.)http:Site/Site3name/controller/action/parm


    5.)So when you get the name of the Site in the index 
method you can respond accordingly or according to the 
site name
```